# Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I am using [MarkdownTextView][1] to add basic markdown to a `UITextView`. The `TextView` is a subclass of `MarkdownTextView`.

However when using copy and paste I get the following error

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class
> MarkdownTextStorage

This is how I use the TextStorage in my ViewController

```
let fonty = UIFont(name: font, size: fsize)
    
attributes.defaultAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = fonty
attributes.orderedListAttributes?[NSFontAttributeName] = fonty
attributes.orderedListItemAttributes?[NSFontAttributeName] = fonty
attributes.unorderedListAttributes?[NSFontAttributeName] = fonty
attributes.unorderedListItemAttributes?[NSFontAttributeName] = fonty

let textStorage = MarkdownTextStorage(attributes: attributes)
    
do {
   textStorage.addHighlighter(try LinkHighlighter())
} catch let error {
    fatalError("Error initializing LinkHighlighter: \(error)")
}
   textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownStrikethroughHighlighter())
   textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownSuperscriptHighlighter())
    
if let codeBlockAttributes = attributes.codeBlockAttributes {
        textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownFencedCodeHighlighter(attributes: codeBlockAttributes))
 }
```

I have used the following initialiser but still have no luck

```
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    attributes = MarkdownAttributes()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}
```

Here's the full source code for the class

```
open class MarkdownTextStorage: HighlighterTextStorage {

fileprivate let attributes: MarkdownAttributes

// MARK: Initialization

/**
Creates a new instance of the receiver.

:param: attributes Attributes used to style the text.

:returns: An initialized instance of `MarkdownTextStorage`
*/
public init(attributes: MarkdownAttributes = MarkdownAttributes()) {
    self.attributes = attributes
    super.init()
    commonInit()
    
    if let headerAttributes = attributes.headerAttributes {
        addHighlighter(MarkdownHeaderHighlighter(attributes: headerAttributes))
    }
    addHighlighter(MarkdownLinkHighlighter())
    addHighlighter(MarkdownListHighlighter(markerPattern: "[*+-]", attributes: attributes.unorderedListAttributes, itemAttributes: attributes.unorderedListItemAttributes))
    addHighlighter(MarkdownListHighlighter(markerPattern: "\\d+[.]", attributes: attributes.orderedListAttributes, itemAttributes: attributes.orderedListItemAttributes))
    
    // From markdown.pl v1.0.1 <http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/>
    
    // Code blocks
    addPattern("(?:\n\n|\\A)((?:(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*\n+)+)((?=^[ ]{0,4}\\S)|\\Z)", attributes.codeBlockAttributes)
    
    // Block quotes
    addPattern("(?:^[ \t]*>[ \t]?.+\n(.+\n)*\n*)+", attributes.blockQuoteAttributes)
    
    // Se-text style headers
    // H1
    addPattern("^(?:.+)[ \t]*\n=+[ \t]*\n+", attributes.headerAttributes?.h1Attributes)
    
    // H2
    addPattern("^(?:.+)[ \t]*\n-+[ \t]*\n+", attributes.headerAttributes?.h2Attributes)
    
    // Emphasis
    addPattern("(\\*|_)(?=\\S)(.+?)(?<=\\S)\\1", attributesForTraits(.traitItalic, attributes.emphasisAttributes))
    
    // Strong
    addPattern("(\\*\\*|__)(?=\\S)(?:.+?[*_]*)(?<=\\S)\\1", attributesForTraits(.traitBold, attributes.strongAttributes))
    
    // Inline code
    addPattern("(`+)(?:.+?)(?<!`)\\1(?!`)", attributes.inlineCodeAttributes)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    attributes = MarkdownAttributes()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

fileprivate func commonInit() {
    defaultAttributes = attributes.defaultAttributes
}

// MARK: Helpers

fileprivate func addPattern(_ pattern: String, _ attributes: TextAttributes?) {
    if let attributes = attributes {
        let highlighter = RegularExpressionHighlighter(regularExpression: regexFromPattern(pattern), attributes: attributes)
        addHighlighter(highlighter)
    }
}

private func attributesForTraits(_ traits: UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits, _ attributes: TextAttributes?) -> TextAttributes? {
    var attributes = attributes
    if let defaultFont = defaultAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] as? UIFont , attributes == nil {
        attributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: fontWithTraits(traits, font: defaultFont)
        ]
    }
    return attributes
}
```

}

Full Error Screenshot

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the issue ?

Comment: How does your `MarkdownTextStorage` object relate to the code you posted? You show that class, but now an instance of `MarkdownTextStorage` gets created. That is likely where your problem lies.

Comment: @DuncanC Apologies, I have updated the question

Comment: The only code you posted that creates a MarkdownTextStorage object uses the `MarkdownTextStorage.init(attributes:)` initializer, so that shouldn't be the cause of your crash. You should look at the stack trace in the crash log and figure out where the init call is coming from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the stack trace and console output you can see that the Objective-C side tries to call the initializer without arguments.

One might think there is one supplied with default value parameter, but that would just work from Swift side, because it is not exposed to the Objective-C side.

So if coming from an Objective-C background one might think, that the intializer might be inherited. But that's not the case with Swift:

> **Initializer Inheritance and Overriding**
>
> Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default.

see here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

**Solution**

So if you supply an initializer without parameters like so:

```
public override convenience init() {
    self.init(attributes: MarkdownAttributes())
}
```

then it works also when called from Objective-C side.